# Is there a Python re.sub that starts from the end?

Tags: python

Is there a version of Python's `re.sub()` that acts like `str.rfind` and begins searching from the last match occurrence?

I want to do a regex substitution on the last match in a string, but there doesn't seem to be an out-of-box solution in the stdlib.

Comment: I guess you’ll have to do `re.findall()` then process the last match

Comment: If you know how a regex engine works, the question does not make much sense (e.g. what will be the "last match" of pattern "a+" in string "aaa"?

Comment: Reverse the line and reverse the regex?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean it literally, no. That's not how the regex engine works.

You can either reverse the string and apply `re.sub(pattern, sub, string, count=1)` with a reversed pattern, like one of the comment said.

Or you can construct a regex that match only the last match, like below:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "hello hello hello hello hello world"
>>> re.sub(r"hello(?!.*hello.*$)", "hay", s)
'hello hello hello hello hay world'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.sub` in the ordinary way but start the regexp with a `(.*)` to match as much of the string as possible, and then in the replacement you could use `\1` to include unchanged the part that the `.*` matched.

```
>>> re.sub("(.*)a", r"\1A", "bananas")
'bananAs'
```

(Note here the `r` to ensure that the `\` is passed verbatim to `re.sub` and not treated as starting an escape sequence.)